# ngClass is not changing color based on variable value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to display green text message when value is true, and red text when value is false.

angular app:

at the top of the controller, I declare my variable and initiate it true:

```
$scope.IsColor = true;

if (response.data.indexOf("Panelists sucessfully added") !== -1) {
    $scope.IsColor = true;
    $scope.Messages = response.data;                            
    angular.element("#msg").focus()
    return true;
}
else {
    $scope.IsColor = false;
    $scope.Messages = response.data;
    angular.element("#msg").focus()                           
    return false;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div id="msg" ng-repeat="msg in Messages" ng-style="IsColor && {'color':'green'} || {'color': 'red'}">{{msg}}</div>
```

No matter what response is, either positive or negative, the text always displays in red.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

Thank you,
Erasmo

UPDATE

More html

```
<body>
    <div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">

                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="Upload" id="btn-upload" ng-click="Upload()" />
                    </div>

                    @* Excel Contents Table *@
                    <table class="table mt-4 mb-5" id="tblPanelists" ng-show="IsVisible">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="p in Panelists">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{p.Name}}</td>
                                <td><a href="mailto:{{p.Email}}">{{p.Email}}</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div id="msg" ng-repeat="msg in Messages" ng-style="IsColor && {'color':'green'} || {'color': 'red'}">{{msg}}</div>
                    <div class=" mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-admin-blue" id="btn-add-panelists" ng-click="AddPanelists()"
                                ng-disabled="disableSubmit">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the angularjs controller-function Add Panelists

The $scope.IsColor boolean is delcare outside the function AddPanelists, within the controller, and used inside the AddPanelists function

AddPanelists function:

```
$scope.AddPanelists = function () {
        $scope.arr = new Array;
        angular.forEach($scope.Panelists, function (item) {
            var b = {
                name: item.Name.trim(),
                email: item.Email.trim()
            };
            $scope.arr.push(b);
        });
        if ($scope.webinarId !== '') {
            if ($scope.arr.length > 0) {
                var data = JSON.stringify({ 'panelists': $scope.arr, 'webId': $scope.webinarId.split(' ').join('') });
                //Call the services
                $http.post('/meetings/panelists/home/createpanelists', data)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.indexOf("Panelists sucessfully added") !== -1) {
                            $scope.IsColor = true;
                            $scope.Messages = response.data;                            
                            angular.element("#msg").focus()
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.IsColor = false;
                            $scope.Messages = response.data;
                            angular.element("#msg").focus()                           
                            return false;
                        }
                    }, function (response) {
                        $scope.IsColor = false;
                        $scope.Messages = "Service unavailable. Please try again.";
                        angular.element("#msg").focus()
                        return false;
                    });
            } else {
                $scope.IsColor = false;
                alert('Please make sure to select a list of Panelists.');
                $scope.Messages = 'Please make sure to select a list of Panelists';
                angular.element("#msg").focus()
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.IsColor = false;
            alert('Please make sure to enter an ID');
            $scope.Messages = 'Please make sure to enter a Zoom Webinar ID';
            angular.element("#msg").focus()
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you show us more code?

Comment: Hello @joohong89 - I included the html and angularjs code that is pertinent to my issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @joohong89 - I thought that the message html section, was outside the div tag with the ngcontroller declaration, but alas, the messages is within the scope.

Comment: the ng-style works fine. somewhere in the function could be off.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an anwser, but there seems to be nothing really wrong as u see in the example.(Except that the $scope.Messages should always be an array instead of string. )

I've tried running your function with a 'mock' http-request, seems to be working fine. You need to check the response that is being returned from the http-request.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyController', function($scope, $q){

        $scope.arr =[1,2,3];
        $scope.webinarId = '1234';
        $scope.IsColor = false;

function mock(isResolve){
  return $q(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
    
      if(isResolve){
          resolve({data:['Panelists sucessfully added','message 1', 'message 2']});
       }else{
           reject({data: ['error 1', 'error 2']});
       }
    }, 1000);
  
  });
}


$scope.AddPanelists = function () {

        
        
        angular.forEach($scope.Panelists, function (item) {
            var b = {
                name: item.Name.trim(),
                email: item.Email.trim()
            };
            $scope.arr.push(b);
        });
        if ($scope.webinarId !== '') {
            if ($scope.arr.length > 0) {
              //  var data = JSON.stringify({ 'panelists': $scope.arr, 'webId': $scope.webinarId.split(' ').join('') });
                //Call the services
              //  $http.post('/meetings/panelists/home/createpanelists', data)
                    mock(true).then(function (response) {
                     
                        if (response.data.indexOf("Panelists sucessfully added") !== -1) {          
                            $scope.IsColor = true;
                            $scope.Messages = response.data;                            
                            angular.element("#msg").focus()
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                           
                            $scope.IsColor = false;
                            $scope.Messages = response.data;
                            angular.element("#msg").focus()                           
                            return false;
                        }
                    }, function (response) {
                    
                    
                        $scope.IsColor = false;
                       
                         // this should be an array as $scope.Messages is used in ng-repeat
                        $scope.Messages = ["Service unavailable. Please try again."];
                        //angular.element("#msg").focus()
                        return false;
                    });
            } else {
                $scope.IsColor = false;
                alert('Please make sure to select a list of Panelists.');
                
                // this should be an array as $scope.Messages is used in ng-repeat
                $scope.Messages = ['Please make sure to select a list of Panelists'];
               // angular.element("#msg").focus()
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.IsColor = false;
            alert('Please make sure to enter an ID');
            
                // this should be an array as $scope.Messages is used in ng-repeat
            $scope.Messages = ['Please make sure to enter a Zoom Webinar ID'];
            angular.element("#msg").focus()
            return false;
        }
    };




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">

                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="Upload" id="btn-upload" ng-click="Upload()" />
                    </div>

                    @* Excel Contents Table *@
                    <table class="table mt-4 mb-5" id="tblPanelists" ng-show="IsVisible">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="p in Panelists">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{p.Name}}</td>
                                <td><a href="mailto:{{p.Email}}">{{p.Email}}</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div id="msg" ng-repeat="msg in Messages" ng-style="IsColor && {'color':'green'} || {'color': 'red'}">{{msg}}</div>
                    <div class=" mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-admin-blue" id="btn-add-panelists" ng-click="AddPanelists()"
                                ng-disabled="disableSubmit">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```